# display: "fullscreen" in web app manifest file does not work

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

`display: "fullscreen"` in my web app manifest file does not work. When I launch the site from my home screen the `display-mode` is **`standalone`**.

(I checked that via `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches`.)

But there is this [article on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#launching_a_page_fullscreen_from_home_screen) saying that you can use it. Is it not supported on Chrome mobile? I especially want that the statusbar at the top is not shown.

Comment: Hi. Are you actually typing it in as `"fullscreen"` or just `fullscreen`, without the `" "`? It might just be defaulting to standalone because of the `" "` characters, but I'm not so sure. Can you post your manifest and if possible, a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Chrome 58 beta/stable immersive *fullscreen* mode is supported for progressive web apps.

To make it work you will have to create a shortcut on your home screen and launch your web app/site with this icon.

This could be done with the **Add to home screen option** in Chrome for Android.

For more information see the following Chromium blog post:
https://blog.chromium.org/2017/03/chrome-58-beta-indexeddb-20_21.html

Answer (score 3):

"fullscreen" is not supported yet. Someone from Google Developers replied that [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/822069102017675268).